# How do you add multiple users to a gitlab project?

Tags: gitlab

I have set up a gitlab project and we authenticate via ldap.

I set up our repo and assumed that everyone who authenticated via ldap would be able to access it but that does not seem to be the case.  I am having to add each user individually.

The project is now set to public but that has not helped.

Is there a way to bulk add users to a project in gitlab?

Comment: you can click on "members" on the side bar and invite others with their email they used for their gitlab account

Comment: Yes but there are about 80 developers in my company I need to add.  I was hoping that there was an automatic way of adding them

Comment: if project visibility is set to "Internal", the documentation says "The project can be accessed by any logged in user)". Of course, public should work too.

Comment: Yeah but I have set it to public and I still seem to have add people one by one once they have logged in

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Apparently my licence had not gone through so I was using a basic version which does not support this!